# What is the best way to open an old project and build it with Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I find that when I download and open an old Android Studio project then follow the suggested Gradle and other upgrades I end up with an UN-build-able mess. Now I find I'm way out of sync for Gradle and Java versions. And the upgrade paths just bugger things up. Most recently I'm trying to compile some of the projects from [Beginning Android Programming with Android Studio, 4th Edition](http://yuliana.lecturer.pens.ac.id/Android/Buku/Wrox.Beginning.Android.Application.Development.Mar.2011.pdf):

```
ftp://ftp.wiley.com/public/vws/9781118705599/Fullcodedownload.zip
Chapter 06 code/WebView
```

What is the proper way to build it? I've opened it in Android Studio, Version Flamingo, or Giraffe or Hedgehog and I always end up unable to build after doing multiple upgrades. What is the proper way to do this?